# Angular 14: Can't resolve Module

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, cypress, e2e-testing

After an sucessful update to Angular 14 our e2e cypress (v9) tests fail to compile. The failure is  caused by an import of that worked before the Angualar update.

It seems like webpack is looking in the wrong directory, since "node_modules" is localed under the project root (`D:\git\template\projects\node_modules`), see below. Why might by the problem and how to solve it?

```
[1] Error: Webpack Compilation Error
[1] ./projects/e2e/integration/demo.spec.ts
[1] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@shift/simulator-plugins/plugins/simulatorplugin/simulatorplugin' in 'D:\git\template\projects\e2e\integration'
[1] resolve '@shift/simulator-plugins/plugins/simulatorplugin/simulatorplugin' in 'D:\git\template\projects\e2e\integration'
[1]   Parsed request is a module
[1]   using description file: D:\git\template\package.json (relative path: ./projects/e2e/integration)
[1]     Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
[1]     Looked for and couldn't find the file at the following paths:
[1] [D:\git\template\projects\e2e\integration\node_modules]
[1] [D:\git\template\projects\e2e\node_modules]
[1] [D:\git\template\projects\node_modules]
[1] [D:\node_modules]
```